# How to construct a composite measure using several items in SPSS?

Tags: spss, pca, factor-analysis

For my master thesis, I have to do a regression analysis. But, as an independent variable, I have to construct a composite measure, being *perceived importance* (of interest groups). I have 9 variables which are: high ability of interest groups in gaining public opinion, legitimacy of interest groups, power of interest groups (which form should form the component *selectivity*), interest groups using direct lobbying, interest groups using letter-writing campaigns (which should form the component *actions*), interest groups focussing on customer issues, interest groups focussing on environmental issues, interest groups focussing on minority rights, and interest groups focussing on economic issues (which should form the component *issue focus)*, on a 5-point Likert-scale ranging from not important at all to very important.

When I run a factor analysis, spss tells me that all variables cluster together into one factor/component. No problem, but I have to get three components ultimately. So, do I now have to run three principal component analyses (for each component seperately)? Or is there a way in which I am able to specify which variables should cluster together beforehand? And what statistics do I need to report/check in order to find out if everything is allowed and valid/reliable? And of course, how do I finally make up the composite measure out of the three components?

As my laptop doesn't allow me to use any better version, I use SPSS version 18.0.

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a software / code question to me. I think the real issue is understanding FA better. IMO, this is on-topic.

Comment: ":I have to get three components ultimately." Why use PCA  then? Factor analysis (partly) tells you the number of components you should have - if you already know how many you need, there's no need for PCA.

Comment: You can also do factor extraction and specify 3 factors (opposite to the default estimate of number-of-factors with eigenvalue>1). Then a varimax/promax rotation could possibly locate the 3 factors meaningfully in the 9-variable-space. If this comes out to give indeed a meaningful structure you can then do the regression using the factorscores.